# Correct use of std::variant and std::visit when functor requires multiple arguments

Tags: c++, c++20, variant

I have been struggling a bit to get my code using `std::variant` in combination with `std::visit` to work. I have now reduced my code to a minimum of just using one type in my variant and still the compiler complains about no matching call to visit.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
class SomeClass {
    
    public:
    
    std::vector<int> foo(const std::string& s, const std::array<float, 3>& d){
        return {};
    }
};

struct Visitor{
    public:
    
    std::vector<int> operator() (SomeClass& c1, const std::string& s, const std::array<float, 3>& a) {
        
        return c1.foo(s, a);        
        
    }
};

int main() {
    
    std::variant<SomeClass> variants;
    
    std::string s = "c++";
    std::array<float, 3> a {1, 0, 0};
    
    std::visit(Visitor{}, variants, s, a);

    return 0;
}
```

In am using gcc 11.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::visit` expects every argument after the visitor to be a `variant`. It will "unwrap" every variant to the underlying object and then make a call to the visitor with all of those objects. It will give an error if you try to give it non-`variant`s like `string`s.

A visitor can have its own internal state/variables. You want to bring `s` and `a` into your visitor. That is, `s` and `a` are not conceptually arguments to the visitor. You should think of them as *part of the visitor*, since the visitor object represents "what to do to the `variant`" and `s` and `a` are *parts* of that. `s` and `a` *are not* inputs to the visitor because the input to the visitor should be the variant.

```
struct Visitor {
    std::string s;
    std::array<float, 3> a;
    std::vector<int> operator()(SomeClass &c) {
        return c.foo(s, a);
    }
};

std::variant<SomeClass> variants;
Visitor v{"c++", {1, 0, 0}};
std::visit(v, variants);
// you *could* shorten this to a lambda with captures
// std::string s = "c++"
// std::array<float, 3> a{1, 0, 0};
// std::visit([&](SomeClass &c) { return c.foo(s, a); }, variants);
// but this will not generalize to multiple things in the variant (lambdas don't overload)
```

There is also the following hack. I would consider it bad style (since it doesn't correctly separate the visitor from what's being visited), but if you must use it works.

```
template<typename T>
std::variant<std::reference_wrapper<T>> unvisit(T &x) {
    return std::ref(x);
}
// using your original Visitor this time
std::variant<SomeClass> variants;
std::string s = "c++";
std::array<float, 3> a {1, 0, 0};

std::visit(Visitor{}, variants, unvisit(s), unvisit(a));
```

I.e. you may wrap every "non-`variant`" argument into a single-variant `variant` by reference and then rely on `visit` to unwrap it again.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using the first suggestion. Although, I found a way to do overloading of lambdas using `template<class... Ts> struct overload : Ts... { using Ts::operator()...; };`
And then:
`std::visit(overload { /*first lambda*/, /*second lambda*/}, variants)`;